# TSQL DateTime issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a simplified case here: a table with 5 fields of startdate, starttime, enddate, endtime and totalduration, all as varchar(20) type. Date fields are in the format like '02/02/2009' and time format like '02:02:00'. There are no null values at all. There is no problem for the following query:

```
  select 
    cast(startdate + ' ' + starttime as datetime) StartDt, 
    cast(enddate + ' ' + endtime as datetime) EndDt,
    convert(datetime, cast(enddate + ' ' + endtime as datetime) - 
      cast(startdate + ' ' + starttime as datetime), 108) as DurationCalc,
    Totalduration
  from myTable
```

This works fine and I get thousand rows data:

```
  StarDt               EndDt     DurationCalc        Totalduration
  2009-01-01 12:00:00  ...       03:34:12            03:34:13
   ....
```

However, when I tried to apply a WHERE clause to filter out rows by differences, I got out-of-range error: "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value":

```
  where 
     cast(startdate + ' ' + starttime as datetime) < 
     cast(enddate + ' ' + endtime as datetime) 
     -- this additional condition caused problem
     and
     datediff(s,
     convert(datetime, cast(enddate + ' ' + endtime as datetime) - 
       cast(startdate + ' ' + starttime as datetime), 108),
     convert(datetime, Totalduration, 108)) > 1
```

Since there are so many rows in my table, it really is hard to identify row by row for the problem. I am not sure what I miss here that invalid rows are not filtered out, or if there is any way to find out the rows where out-of-range exist? Any suggestions?

If I remove the "additional condition" datediff(...), I can get rows as result. There seems no any problems in the first few rows. I applied the Top 1 to select, I still get out-of-range error.

Comment: What is TotalDuration? You are trying to convert it into a DateTime; can it be converted? What does data stored in TotalDuration look like?

Comment: I can't see why there is a cast to string? Can you not just add the date and times?

Comment: actually the MS SQL Management Studio's query does displays all the rows till the problem one. If there is an error, the result tab is focused. You can see the results tab where all the good rows are displayed.

Comment: TotalDuration is in a format of time like '01:23:00'. The problem is actually this field. Some durations are '25:xx:xx', which is not valid time (hours > 24). I finally located the problem from Studio's query results (partial ones or all the possible good ones) with an error message, as my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

Sql Server has an [IsDate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function.  Use it to identify your problem rows.  Then *fix* the table to keep the data as DateTime columns in the first place.

Comment: Careful: don't try to combine the offending query with an extra ISDATE in a WHERE or CASE clause: you'll probably still get an error because SQL Server has a weird way of not optimizing away expressions. Because the offending rows were wanted in the first place, this is not much of a problem, but *don't* try it to get the non-offending rows converted and all.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before usually its due to US vs UK date formats, it depends on how the data was inserted into the database.

Another issue (related) is that when using datetime, and you use date as a parameter, you always need to add 1 extra day to your end date when doing date ranges (or date difference calculations)

**Darknight**